# How can I prevent content in column two from affecting the position of content in column one?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need this input text container to stay in place in this layout. After i submit the input text, data displayed container's height will increase which usually pushes the Input Text container down.

[image: How the containers should look]

However, if i use absolute position. It works fine until i submit and then I cannot use the text area or the submit button unless i reload the page. I think it is because the contents of the input container moves?

I tried position absolute but that led to the input being unusable after 1 submit.

I tried removing it but then the input container would go to the bottom. I tried transform: translate (-50%, -50%) and tried moving all the children of the input container but that did not work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container position-relative">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- First container -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 order-1 order-md-0">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <h2>Car Park Number</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 2nd container with position-absolute -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 input-container order-2 position-absolute mb-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Enter Car Park Number Prefix:</h5>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="carParkNumberInput" rows="3" placeholder="Enter prefix (e.g. TY)" oninput="validateInputForPrefix(this)"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-primary ripple mt-3" id="submitPrefixBtn">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd container -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 order-0 order-md-1">
      <div class="card custom-height-card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="yourContainerId" class="row"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning rarely has a use in a primary layout. Don't implement it unless you understand what it does, which includes taking the element out of normal document flow.

You need to look at your layout from outside in. You're trying to implement three columns, but really you have just two. The first has two stacked children. The second has one child. When set up correctly the content of the second column has no impact on the height or position of the first.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container position-relative">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- First container -->
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <h2>Car Park Number</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="input-container mt-3 mb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Enter Car Park Number Prefix:</h5>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="carParkNumberInput" rows="3" placeholder="Enter prefix (e.g. TY)" oninput="validateInputForPrefix(this)"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-primary ripple mt-3" id="submitPrefixBtn">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd container -->
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="card custom-height-card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="yourContainerId" class="row">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```